# There's no help in Help in Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

There's no help in Help in Android app. Nothing about how to use the app. Maybe the link should be called 'About'. Going to meta is not real documentation.

Comment: What would you like an internal Help page to include?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, this is a tangential note, but it'd be awesome if *new* signups through the app got the "about" page (aka /tour) before getting to the feed...

Comment: @Kasra For one, how to use search. The search syntax doesn't seem to be the same as the website. See my other post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217815/why-search-by-title-in-android-app-does-not-work-like-website

Comment: @kasra, my first question is how do I delete my answer that I just posted?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi it should include a link to faq too. This would be useful as many new users get introduced to se through android app. Like me!