# Why search by title in Android app does not work like website?

Tags: support, status-completed, android-app

I searched using: +title:right [sql] and I didn't get posts with 'right' in the title. So is search in the android app work differently than the website? The results from SO and the app are very different

Comment: The app is limited to using the API so yes, everything is very different.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the API isn't parsing the + correctly.  If you leave it out, [it works fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5gunpl.png).  Digging...

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in (the as yet unreleased) search API backing the mobile app.  The sites know to strip out `+`, but the API was just dropping the "unknown search term" `+title`.

This was fixed in the latest deploy, you shouldn't need an app update for it take effect.