# Android app needs help and new user guidance

Tags: feature-request, android-app, help-center

This is a partial duplicate of ["There's no help in Help in Android app"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217790/theres-no-help-in-help-in-android-app), but I think just asking for help doesn't go far enough.

Yes, it would be great if the app included all of the normal sites' help centers, presumably with a lot of content modified to reflect how to do things in the app, and maybe some more generic "how do I use the app?" content.

But that's a big project, and there are people trying to use the app *now*. Today on cooking we had a new user come to us, really concerned about all the unwritten rules all the self-declared moderators kept enforcing, asking ["What are the rules?"](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/what-are-the-rules) We need to make sure the app is "safe" for these users too. (And they posted it on the main site, begging for it to be left open for a day or two to get answered, since they hadn't discovered meta through the app!)

So to be specific, the help page in the app needs a few things:

- a pointer to site-specific metas, for questions about rules
- a disclaimer that the app does *not* have all the features
- pointers to help centers (making it clear that each site has their own)

And on top of that, the app could probably use some kind of louder warning that it does not yet have all features, and you might have to visit the real site - maybe even the dreaded interstitial page.

Comment: @rumtscho ...oops! I did go a bit further with my suggestions, but I think we can indeed consolidate these.

Comment: I explained the situation to the SO moderators and asked them to decide which version they prefer to keep. But yes, I also thought about consolidation after one is closed, because I think we both touched on points the other one didn't mention.